# is it possible to develop hybrid application without using phone gap or quick connect?

Tags: iphone

I am new to this iPhone development.I would like to create a hybrid application or iPhone.I want to know is it possible to develop hybrid application without using any of the external frameworks or libraries like phonegap or quickconnect or titanium .I just want to know is it possible to create an hybrid application with just HTML file JavaScript files and CSS file and x code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind phonegap (can't stress this enough titanium is NOT the same), is that a webview is created in the app and the HTML, CSS, javascript etc. is added to this. Then some other logic allows you to access some of the underlying features like the camera.

So creating a native iPhone application where you create a webview and code the HTML is basically the same idea (as phonegap not titanium, titanium cross complies into native code).

Comment: so your are telling its posible to develop a hybrid application withiut any of these framework

Comment: yes in some way, a webview is basically a browser without the address bar (similar to an iframe). It can take in HTML and render it, you could add in jquery etc into the webview same as a browser. so yes you could create an app by telling it to open a webview and create everything else with HTML, by no means is it a good way to develop an app but possible yes

Comment: so if i wish to add HTML files and JS files in to xcode. Will i be able to access these files from .m files and also can i give css property for the UIbutton through CSS files

Comment: you will be able to add / use any file type you wish, this is not limited to xcode, every platform i no of will allow you to add any filetype into a folder. no as I said you can open a webview and add HTML, you can add a HTML button and style that. If you where doing this the only native code, control etc. would be the webview, everything else would be excatly the same as developing a website

Comment: will i be able to give css property for the buttins in IB also ie the object in the xcode?

Comment: you will be able to give a css stle to any html element inside the webview,NOTHING else, no native controls, no native buttons. It will be as though you are running a website inside your app with very little connection to the underlying feature of objective-c, if you want to access anything such as camera or database you will need to make some special functions as phonegap does. doing this you will use no native controls in anyway, it will be html buttons, labels, ing tags etc.

Comment: so if i want to give some action to native button through JS function is it possible?

Comment: no, as i have said it will completly indapendant of this, it will be abstracted away from the native controls. There may be very advance ways of do it but to understand this you would have to learn a lot of objective-c and IOS, to such as point that it would not make sense to go and do this. If you need to use this, then you need a native app

Comment: i would like to whether these can be attained through phonegap or quickconnect

Comment: NO! (never used quickconnect). what phonegap does is 1. create a webview, 2. make a mobile website. 3. add it to webview. they add in functions to allow you access the camera and a few others but that is it, they use tools like dojo or jquery to make mobile webpages inside this webview that are connected in NO WAY to the underlying objective-c controls. Titanium cross complies down to the native code and will allow a lot more low level stuff than phonegap, but still not fully. Most of these answers are very easy to find online, you will need to do research yourself